# Only create coupon on specific product purchase woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to create coupon on specific product purchase. Can you please tell me where i am doing wrong

```
function coupon_code_akki($order_id){
 $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
$items = $order->get_items();
foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
}
if ($product_id ='10351'){
 $bname= $order->get_billing_first_name();
 $bemail= $order->get_billing_email();   
 $coupon = new WC_Coupon();
 $coupon->set_code( $bname . '1990' );
 $coupon->set_amount( 1990);
 $coupon->set_email_restrictions($bemail)
 $coupon->save();
 echo 'done';
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly or at what stage are you using this code?

I think the problem is here:
`if ($product_id ='10351'){`

In this section, you should check by putting two equals. The equals operator is like this: `==`

`if ($product_id == '10351'){`

And here is the error:
`$coupon->set_email_restrictions($bemail)`

You should use a semicolon at the end.

```
function coupon_code_akki($order_id){
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    $items = $order->get_items();
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
    }
    
    if (!empty($product_id) && $product_id == '10351'){
        $bname= $order->get_billing_first_name();
        $bemail= $order->get_billing_email();
        $coupon = new WC_Coupon();
        $coupon->set_code( $bname . '1990' );
        $coupon->set_amount( 1990);
        $coupon->set_email_restrictions($bemail);
        $coupon->save();
        echo 'done';
    }
}
```

If you want me to help you, just tell me at what stage you want to create a coupon.